# Making a starter when reusing yeast

Tags: yeast, yeast-starters, reusing-yeast

I want to reuse the washed yeast from a previous batch of beer in my next batch. Should I make a starter for it? If so, how much of it? I looked at MrMalty, and it seems to me they tell me not to make a starter for this. So how much yeast starter should I make? Should I just repitch the washed yeast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't necessarily need to make a starter if you are re-pitching within a few weeks because the viability of the yeast will still be pretty high.  But, if you store the yeast for much time you should always make a starter.  This ensures that the yeast is still viable and it will help ensure the yeast are active so you don't have a long lag time during fermentation.

I frequently wash yeast for use in future batches and always make a starter.  It gives me a little peace of mind because I know for certain that the yeast are viable before pitching.

Comment: I'll try this with my next batch. Washed the yeast from my last batch that I put into the keg yesterday and put most of it in the refridgerator and about a 100ml I used in a starter. Gonna use it in a brew tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This answer has not yet been tested by experience.*

I saved the yeast from our last 4 brews, but I haven't used any of it yet.  Although it was my impression that the washed yeast could simply be repitched, I was planning on treating it like dry yeast, and proofing it just to test my storage more than anything else.

You'll note the quantity of yeast slurry **does** change on the calculator, and I don't know about you, but when I adjust the sliders to represent the near solid yeast cake I've saved, it looks like I only need half of what's there, so a starter while perfectly acceptable, should be unnecessary.